# Maven build downloading from wrong link

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, artifactory

I'm trying to build my project using Maven but when my dependencies start to download. The download link for Jackson-annotation is incorrect. The version is not added to the link as shown below (${jackson.version.annotations}).

```
https://na.artifactory.blabla.com/artifactory/sysdse-maven-blabla/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/${jackson.version.annotations}/jackson-annotations-${jackson.version.annotations}.pom
```

I am pulling my dependencies from artifactory. So the repository is correct just not the version.

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the error message I am getting.

```
WARN org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven - The POM for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.7 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.7
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for junit:junit:jar is missing. @
ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Failed to execute goal on project cde-pilot: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ibm:cde-pilot:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.7 -> com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:${jackson.version.annotations}: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:${jackson.version.annotations}: Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:pom:${jackson.version.annotations} from/to artifactory-release (https://na.artifactory.blabla.com/artifactory/sysdse-maven-blabla): Illegal character in path at index 117: https://na.artifactory.blabla.com/artifactory/sysdse-maven-blabla/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/${jackson.version.annotations}/jackson-annotations-${jackson.version.annotations}.pom
```

---

UPDATE:
I found this weird set up in my Pom hierarchy. It shows that there is a conflict with the version.

[image]

I fixed this issue by removing the dependency from the pom and the repository file in the .m2 directory and adding again the package to the pom.

---

But now Im getting this error:

```
'parent.artifactId' must be changed, the parent element cannot have the same groupId:artifactId as the project
```

---

Here is my POM:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>zpe-lap</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ZPE</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>quartz</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>soap</groupId>
            <artifactId>soap</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oro</groupId>
            <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.util</groupId>
            <artifactId>ws-commons-util</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>ws-commons-java5</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlrpc-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlrpc-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ezmorph</groupId>
            <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <classifier>jdk13</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.sdwb</groupId>
            <artifactId>cmvc-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.15.134</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.bluepages</groupId>
            <artifactId>bluepages-java-toolkit</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>dv2common</artifactId>
            <version>0.93</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.swt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86</artifactId>
            <version>4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>FTPProtocol</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>dv2pm</artifactId>
            <version>0.93</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>databasetools</artifactId>
            <version>0.93</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.telelogic.focalpoint</groupId>
            <artifactId>focalpoint-webservices2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-soapclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>NCSO</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>odtclient</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>tctapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>tct</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.retain</groupId>
            <artifactId>retain-toolkit</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.sport</groupId>
            <artifactId>sport-wrappers</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.sport</groupId>
            <artifactId>sport-commandline</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2java</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.mylyn.github</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.egit.github.core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: The property is set in the jackson-parent pom. Maven should download that automatically. I'm not familiar with artifactory but with nexus you would need to make sure that maven central is either proxied, mirrored or reachable directly.

Comment: I am also using Jenkins to do my builds. Artifactory is where we pull our approved dependencies. Im not sure about adding maven central. I just want to fix the pom file that is in artifactory. Im not sure where to edit that. I dont know if I uploaded the jar file correctly to my repo

Comment: The pom in your repo is most probably not broken but you need the corresponding parent <parent>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson</groupId>
    <!-- this is one of few Jackson modules that depends on parent and NOT jackson-bom -->
    <artifactId>jackson-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
  </parent> in your repository.

Comment: I got it to work but now Its showing a different error

Comment: Did you change any of the jackson poms? You should not do this... If the error relates to your pom post the complete pom.xml of your project. It seems you defined a parent with an artifactId identical with the one of the project itself.

Comment: I posted my POM and I didnt change the jackson poms. I just uploaded the jar file and asked artifactory to generate the internal pom files for me

Comment: I think you have to use the original pom and not one generated by artifactory

Comment: I tried both and same issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add this to your pom.xml?

```
<properties>
<jackson.annotations.version>2.9.7</jackson.annotations.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: No I havent. I would assume by having the `<version>` would take care of that. This would go under the `<dependency>` tag?

Comment: `${jackson.version.annotations}` is a variable. `<version>` is just a tag, and you can't call this variable without defining it. The snippet code i provide you will go under the `<properties>` tag.